# Convert XML to JSON and Vice Versa and also how to identify REST endpoint while making XML Request?

Tags: java, json, xml, spring-boot

My company has exposed REST endpoint to external world through Proxy/Gateway. Around 1000 of customers are on-boarded to Proxy/Gateway and making XML request to SOAP based system (deployed on WebSphere App Server (WAS) V7.5).

Now, we've developed new system which only supports JSON and wanted to point to newly developed system which deployed on PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry).

Here we don't want to ask Consumers to make any changes.

Now, we're trying to developed Adapter (Spring Boot Project) which converts XML request to JSON make a request to new system and get response in JSON and again Adapter (Spring Boot Project) converts JSON to XML. Here, JSON response and XML response could be different at times.

Now, I am really not able to make any decision which endpoint to call to

```
String xml_data = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:ahc.com:dms:wsdls:organization\">\n" + 
        "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" + 
        "   <soapenv:Body>\n" + 
        "      <urn:getRoles>\n" + 
        "         <getRolesRequest>\n" + 
        "            <Type>ABC</Type>\n" + 
        "         </getRolesRequest>\n" + 
        "      </urn:getRoles>\n" + 
        "   </soapenv:Body>\n" + 
        "</soapenv:Envelope>";
JSONObject obj = XML.toJSONObject(xml_data);
System.out.println(obj);
```

It gives me below response.

```
{"soapenv:Envelope":{"soapenv:Body":{"urn:getRoles":{"getRolesRequest":{"Type":"AYU"}}},"xmlns:soapenv":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","xmlns:urn":"urn:ahc.com:dms:wsdls:organization","soapenv:Header":""}}
```

Any guidance ?

Note: I want to remove `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\` from JSON object. Also, while convering JSON to XML I want to add `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\`

Comment: I'm sorry what is the `endpoint` you are talking about? You are not sure which API endpoint to call with JSON?

Comment: I am assuming your code is outside the REST project, you should have `SOAP to REST` mapping to help you find the URL. One way to solve is to configure the `Gateway` to provide the REST URL as `header`.

Comment: I am not sure what `Gateway` is used. Lot of gateways provide configurations for each endpoint that's added. We can ask it to add custom headers when a request is made on a URL that way when it adds REST url as a header, you can read it and use that route your call further. If your gateway is another app custom written, it should be modified to support this functionality I believe.

Comment: If your gateway does not support it, another way is to configure your `adapter` application to contain those mappings. configure your environment to load the mappings on initial application loading and use them to identify the REST endpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204623/discussion-between-sunil-dabburi-and-paa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library. It has static methods to read xml and generate json.

```
    String xmlData = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""
    + " xmlns:urn=\"urn:ahc.com:dms:wsdls:organization\">\n"
    + "   <soapenv:Header/>\n"
    + "   <soapenv:Body>\n"
    + "      <urn:getRoles>\n"
    + "         <getRolesRequest>\n"
    + "            <Type>ABC</Type>\n"
    + "         </getRolesRequest>\n"
    + "      </urn:getRoles>\n"
    + "   </soapenv:Body>\n"
    + "</soapenv:Envelope>";
    Map<String, Object> jsonData = U.<Map<String, Object>>get(
        U.<Map<String, Object>>fromXmlWithoutNamespaces(xmlData), "Envelope.Body.getRoles");
    System.out.println(U.toJson(jsonData));
```

Output:

```
{
  "getRolesRequest": {
    "Type": "ABC"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Gateway supports passing custom header for every endpoint, that would be the ideal way to do this. In such a case, it will send the REST endpoint in the request header, you can use that to forwarding calls.

If Gateway does not support such functionality, you can try modifying your `Adapter` code.

If you want to configure your adapter to hold the endpoint mappings, you can configure it using `@ConfigurationProperties`

`EndpointRegistry` class

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "endpoint")
@Component
public class EndpointRegistry {

    // top key - endpoint
    // one key - soapUrl
    // another key - restUrl
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> api;

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getApi() {
        return api;
    }

    public void setApi(Map<String, Map<String, String>> api) {
        this.api = api;
    }
}
```

This will match the key pattern mentioned in your `application.properties` file as below

```
endpoint.api.endpoint1.soapUrl=<soap-url>
endpoint.api.endpoint1.restUrl=<rest-url>

endpoint.api.endpoint2.soapUrl=<soap-url>
endpoint.api.endpoint2.restUrl=<rest-url>
```

Now, `endpoint name` should be unique. You can decide on the key structure. This is just an example.

Here is a test controller to verify the values:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/endpoints")
public class EndpointController {

    @Autowired
    EndpointRegistry registry;

    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, String> getRestUrl(String endpoint) {
        return registry.getApi().get(endpoint);
    }
}
```

Make a `GET` call to `http://localhost:8080/endpoints?endpoint=endpoint1`

You should get

```
{
   "soapUrl":"<soap-url>",
   "restUrl":"<rest-url>"
}
```

This way, you can use your `EndpointRegistry` to get the required URLs and make calls.

You can use the Spring Configuration server to update your application.properties for each environment. Check it here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html

Meanwhile, you can configure your CI pipeline to add these properties beforehand for each environment.